# Why are measure spaces defined as a triple when just the sigma algebra and measure will do?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I always see measure spaces denoted as something like $(\Omega, F, \mu)$, where

- $\Omega$ is a (nonempty) set
- $F$ is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$
- $\mu$ is a measure

But the definition of the sigma algebra $F$ requires $\Omega \in F$. Because we can simply recover $\Omega$ from $\Omega = \cup_{s \in F} s$ we see that it's superfluous to define a measure space as a triple.

So why are measure spaces defined as a triple when just the sigma algebra and measure will do?

Comment: For the same reason why we write $(\Omega, \tau)$ for a topological space.

Comment: Just for convenience I would say. We also speak of a function $f:X\to Y $ while domain  $X $ can be found on base of $f $.

Comment: "Let $(F,\mu)$ be a measure space, and $\Omega = \cup_{s \in F}s$" is more tedious to write than "Let $(\Omega, F, \mu)$ be a measure space." You may as well ask why for a function we write "let $f: X \to Y$" when $X$ and $Y$ are part of the definition of $f$.

Comment: Why is a group considered to be a **set** together with certain operations, when, in fact, you can deduce the set from the operations?

Comment: Technically, $\mu$ by itself suffices, since $F$ is its domain. But the $(\Omega,F,\mu)$ formulation more closely matches how we usually think of measure spaces. We begin with the set that will underlie the whole thing, and only after that's in place we think about what subsets should are sufficiently well-behaved to count as measurable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really say "$F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra" without specifying $\Omega$, because the definition of $\sigma$-algebra requires there to be an $\Omega$.  Of
course if you really wanted you could say $F$ is a $\sigma$-ring such that $\bigcup_{s \in F} s \in F$ (and that union is then defined as $\Omega$).  But why bother?  In nearly all cases of interest where you consider a measure space, 
$\Omega$ is given or constructed pretty much at the beginning.

Comment: My point is $\Omega$ is a dependency on the sigma algebra, not the measure space.